# What properties/fields are included (System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer)?

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer, system.text.json

Which of the following are included by JsonSerializer?

|  | Private/Protected/Internal Fields | Private/Protected/Internal Properties | Public Fields | Public Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Readonly |  |  |  |  |
| Writeonly |  |  |  |  |
| Read & Write |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

|  | Private OR Protected OR Internal Fields OR Properties | Public Fields - | Public Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Readonly | ❌ | Default: ❌ ✔ if IncludeFields (default false) **AND** !IgnoreReadOnlyFields (default false) | Default: ✔ if !IgnoreReadOnlyProperties (default false) |
| Writeonly | ❌ | Default: ❌ ✔ if IncludeFields (default false) | ✔ |
| Read & Write | ❌ | Default: ❌ ✔ if IncludeFields (default false) | ✔ |